# Not able to view tables while doing data comparison in Visual Studio 2012 using SSDT

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools, compression

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2008 R2 express. I am trying to use Data Comparison tool provided with VS 2012. After selecting databases on first page of wizard, when I move next page the tables in my databases are not visible.

[Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw07F.png)

[Wizard first Page][2]

[Wizard Second Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSm6r.png)

As you can see in the Wizard second image Tables in database schema are not visible.

I am new to this data comparison tool. Please let me know if I have missed anything here.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Do you have primary keys on your tables? The Data Comparison tool won't work unless both sides have the same Primary Keys (and possibly the same structure, too - haven't ever tried without the same structure). Red-Gate's SQL Data Compare can work without PKs by defining the key columns, but MS doesn't allow this.